# Renaming list elements (elem0 elem2 to elem0 elem1 ) after deleting nodes XSLT 1.0

Tags: sorting, xslt, dynamic

Update: I appreciate all the help. I was able to get the Process elem tags to work with the help from you guys but my boss has a new requirement. I have to move elements to a new place (instead of removing them) and properly put elem numbers. Thanks again, you guys are the best!

**Previous Problem:**

> I am new to xslt so please bear with me.  So here is the problem.  I
>   have this xml:
>
> ```
>  <Process>
>           <elem0>
>              <pcode>xx<pcode>
>           </elem0>
>           <elem1>
>              <pcode>xy<pcode>
>           </elem1>
>           <elem2>
>              <pcode>ab<pcode>
>           </elem2>
>           <elem3>
>              <pcode>AD<pcode>
>           </elem3>               
>     </Process>
> ```
>
> And I have to erase elements with pcode value='xy', which I am doing
>   it successfully with xslt. However, after doing that you will see
>   there is a gap in element (elem0 elem2 elem3) names.
>
> ```
> <Process>
>       <elem0>
>          <pcode>xx<pcode>
>       </elem0>
>       <elem2>
>          <pcode>ab<pcode>
>       </elem2>
>       <elem3>
>          <pcode>AD<pcode>
>       </elem3>               
> </Process>
> ```
>
> I would like for it to be
>
> ```
> <Process>
>           <elem0>
>              <pcode>xx<pcode>
>           </elem0>
>           <elem1>
>              <pcode>ab<pcode>
>           </elem1>
>           <elem2>
>              <pcode>AD<pcode>
>           </elem2>               
>     </Process> so it shows up properly in front end, but I am stuck. Tried sorting but didn't work. elem identifications are
> ```
>
> changing so it is harder for me to use a template of some sort. Thanks
>   in advice!

**UPDATED: with new requirement to move some elements to a new place, instead of removing them. I apologize for the inconvenience and appreciate all of your help in advance.**

I have this xml:

```
 <Process>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xx<pcode>
          </elem0>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem1>
          <elem2>
             <pcode>ab<pcode>
          </elem2>
          <elem3>
             <pcode>AD<pcode>
          </elem3>               
    </Process>
```

And I have to MOVE(erase-old requirement) elements with pcode value='xy'to EdProcess, which I am doing it successfully with xslt. However, after doing that you will see there is a gap in element (elem0 elem2 elem3) names. Also, EdProcess needs to start at elem0, and any new elements that gets moved should be in order, i.e elem0, elem1, elem2, etc.

```
<Process>
      <elem0>
         <pcode>xx<pcode>
      </elem0>
      <elem2>
         <pcode>ab<pcode>
      </elem2>
      <elem3>
         <pcode>AD<pcode>
      </elem3>               
</Process>



<EdProcess>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem1>
   </EdProcess>
```

I would like for it to be

```
<Process>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xx<pcode>
          </elem0>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>ab<pcode>
          </elem1>
          <elem2>
             <pcode>AD<pcode>
          </elem2>               
    </Process>

 <EdProcess>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem0>
   </EdProcess>
```

so it shows up properly in front end, but I am stuck. Tried sorting but didn't work. elem identifications are changing so it is harder for me to use a template of some sort. Thanks in advice!

Comment: This isn't a very good XML format--it complicates any sort of processing you might want to do on it. Element names should be fixed. If you need numbering (and you don't really need it, it seems), add an attribute and put the number in the attribute value.

Comment: @FrancisAvila A good point. However, OP may not have control over the schema.

Comment: yeah I don't have any control over the schema. It is used almost in every list that our firm uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your source format doesn't have other elements intermingled with the `elem`s, there's a very simple and straightforward way to do this that doesn't require preceding/following-sibling or a double-pass:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[pcode != 'xy']" mode="elems" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="elems">
    <xsl:element name="elem{position() - 1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input:

```
<Process>
  <elem0>
    <pcode>xx</pcode>
  </elem0>
  <elem1>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem1>
  <elem2>
    <pcode>ab</pcode>
  </elem2>
  <elem3>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem3>
  <elem4>
    <pcode>AD</pcode>
  </elem4>
</Process>
```

Produces:

```
<Process>
  <elem0>
    <pcode>xx</pcode>
  </elem0>
  <elem1>
    <pcode>ab</pcode>
  </elem1>
  <elem2>
    <pcode>AD</pcode>
  </elem2>
</Process>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixes my earlier problem, but now I am facing a new requirement where I have to move any elements with pcode = 'xy' inside <EdProcess>, and properly order elem N tags. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NickJones Since this is an entirely new requirement, could you restore your previous question text and create a new question for the new requirement?

Comment: Just did as you asked. Thanks again.

Comment: @NickJones I think you partially misunderstood me. What I meant was to create a whole separate question on this site to ask the new question, rather than adding the new requirement to this ome.

Answer (score 0):

Since XSLT doesn't do updateable variables the most straightforward approach I can see to this is a recursive template that deals with one sibling at a time

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Process>
      <!-- start with the first child -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Process/*[pcode != 'xy'][1]" />
    </Process>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="nextIndex" select="0" />
    <xsl:element name="elem{$nextIndex}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </xsl:element>
    <!-- process the next applicable sibling, if any, incrementing the index -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[pcode != 'xy'][1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="nextIndex" select="$nextIndex + 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a two-pass XSLT pattern, and rename all the elements in the second pass:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="pass1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Process"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($pass1)" mode="pass2" />
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Process" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
       <xsl:element name="{ concat('elem', position()) }">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that for XSLT 1, you need to use the `node-set()` function, which is included in most XSLT 1 processors, but you will need to include the namespace declaration at the top of your stylesheet. For ESLT-aware processors (Saxon, xsltproc, Xalan-J, jd.xslt, and 4XSLT) use `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` and `exsl:node-set()`. For Xalan-C use `xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and `xalan:nodeset()`. For MSXSL use `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and `msxsl:node-set()`.

Comment: That would work nicely with XSLT 2.0 (in 1.0 you'd need a `node-set` extension function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preceding-sibling` axis to count the number of elements that appear *before* your current `elem*` element. Then subtract the number that would have been deleted, and you have your current number:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Process/*">
        <!-- only copy if not "xy" -->
        <xsl:if test="pcode!='xy'">
            <!-- number of preceding elements which are also not "xy" -->
            <xsl:element name="elem{count(preceding-sibling::*[pcode!='xy'])}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That said, this is a terrible XML format and you should change this format if you can so it doesn't have unknown element names like `elem0`. If you need to know an element's position in a list, you can easily get it with `position()`, `count(preceding-sibling::*)`, etc. If you *really* need an explicit number, put it in an attribute, not in the element name, e.g. `<elem num="1">`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a one-pass solution that correctly processes `elem`N elements that can be at any place in the tree -- not only siblings.  None of the other answers processes such XML document correctly.**

**It is fairly efficient -- in the case when the tree is with limited depth its efficiency is close to linear (O(N)). It *is* linear if all such elements are siblings**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select=
      "$pCount + count(.//*[starts-with(name(), 'elem') and not(pcode='xy')])"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'elem') and not(pcode='xy')]">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
  <xsl:element name="elem{$pCount}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount+1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select=
     "$pCount+1+ count(.//*[starts-with(name(), 'elem') and not(pcode='xy')])"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'elem') and pcode='xy']">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<Process>
  <a/>
  <elem0>
    <pcode>xx</pcode>
      <elem1>
        <pcode>xy</pcode>
      </elem1>
      <elem2>
        <pcode>xz</pcode>
      </elem2>
 </elem0>
  <b/>
  <elem3>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem3>
  <c/>
  <elem4>
    <pcode>ab</pcode>
  </elem4>
  <d/>
  <elem5>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem5>
  <e/>
  <elem6>
    <pcode>AD</pcode>
  </elem6>
  <f/>
</Process>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Process>
   <a/>
   <elem0>
      <pcode>xx</pcode>
      <elem1>
         <pcode>xz</pcode>
      </elem1>
   </elem0>
   <b/>
   <c/>
   <elem2>
      <pcode>ab</pcode>
   </elem2>
   <d/>
   <e/>
   <elem3>
      <pcode>AD</pcode>
   </elem3>
   <f/>
</Process>
```